# NSPredicate on custom object

Tags: swift, class, object, nspredicate

I have an array 'var listOfCodesTemp = Code' of the following class

```
class Code {
var code: String
var description: String

init(code: String, description: String) {
    self.code = code
    self.description = description
}}
```

Now I want to filter this array according to the user input related to the variable 'code'.
This is the code that I'am currently using

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "code CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (listOfCodesTemp as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredListOfCodesTemp = array as! [Code]
```

But this one is leading to the following error
...does not implement methodSignatureForSelector:

I looked up on some similar question but could't find a solution. I thankful for any tip I could get.

Thank you all in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to inherit from `NSObject`:

```
class Code: NSObject {
var code: String
var description: String

init(code: String, description: String) {
    self.code = code
    self.description = description
}}
```

You will have to change your `description` variable name though at it overrides the corresponding variable of `NSObject`.